# How to solve "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined" reactjs + django

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jwt

i'm practicing reactjs watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rh853GTgKo&list=PLJRGQoqpRwdfoa9591BcUS6NmMpZcvFsM&index=9

I want to verify my information using uid and token, but I don't know how to deliver it.

In this code: Activate.js in container

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { verify } from '../actions/auth';

const Activate = ({ verify, match }) => {
const [verified, setVerified] = useState(false);

const verify_account = e => {
  const uid = match.params.uid; // I Think This part is Problem
  const token = match.params.token;

  verify(uid, token);
  setVerified(true);
};


if (verified) {
   return <Redirect to='/' />
}
```

and this code : auth.js in actions

```
export const verify = (uid, token) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };

  const body = JSON.stringify({ uid, token });

  try {
    await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/users/activation/`, body, config);

    dispatch ({
      type: ACTIVATION_SUCCESS,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch ({
      type: ACTIVATION_FAIL
    });
  }
}
```

i think i didn't render uid, token but i confused how to do that

App.js code:

```
<Router>
  <Layout>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path ='/activate/:uid/:token'>
        <Activate />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Layout>
</Router>
```

I'd appreciate any help. :)

Comment: Can you post your actual error? By the way, it seems that `match` is undefined in some way

Comment: @DDomen  what is actual error?  in my chrome console " const uid = match.params.uid;" has a problem " “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined”"

Comment: Stack trace? In which line are you getting the error? Also where do you call the `Activate` function? Because it seems that the `match` parameter is `undefined`

Comment: `match` should be injected into the props by the parent `Route` component.  Is there another place in your app that you use the `Activate` component where it's not a child of a `Route`?

Comment: You have an issue with `verify`.  You wrote that your `Activate` component takes a prop `verify`, so within the scope of that function the variable `verify` will refer to the prop `verify` rather than the function `verify` that you imported.  If you want to refer to the function, ditch the prop with the same variable.

Comment: But you'll still have an issue because `verify` is an action creator.  You are creating the action but you are not dispatching it.  It's a double arrow function and you are only executing the first part.  The result of calling `verify(uid, token);` is a function of `dispatch`, ie. a "thunk" action which needs to be dispatched.

Comment: Oh! Now I see that you are using the `connect` HOC and just left off that part of the code.  So if you are getting `verify` through your `mapDispatchToProps` then ignore those last two comments :)

Comment: @Linda Paiste  Thanks for the detailed explanation, I got to understand route and match better. thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) hook to extract `uid` and `token` params:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Redirect, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { verify } from '../actions/auth';

const Activate = ({ verify }) => {
const [verified, setVerified] = useState(false);
const { uid, token } = useParams();

const verify_account = e => {
  verify(uid, token);
  setVerified(true);
};


if (verified) {
   return <Redirect to='/' />
}
```

Comment: `useParams` is good for clarity, but they are using this as a render function for a `Route` so they *should* be getting `match` in the props.  There is a lot else wrong with their code though.  Hard to say exactly where the breakdown is that causes this particular error.